# Dinning philosophers problem MPI C++. Everytime process 0 exit without using finalize

Tags: c++, mpi

I have some troubles with solving of the problem and i dont know what to do here. Everytime when i compile this code i get the same error :
"job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] process exited without calling finalize

[1-5] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[0] on USER-PC
Philosophers.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0x80000003"

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
#include "mpi.h"
#define FORK_REQUEST 1
#define FORK_RESPONSE 2
#define FORK_RELEASE 3

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank;
    int size;
    //init MPI
    if (MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 2;
    }
    if (MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 3;
    }

    if (!rank) {
        printf("Hello from table %d \n", rank);
        int in_buffer[1];
        int out_buffer[1];
        int philosopher;
        MPI_Status status;

        std::list<int> queue;

        bool* fork = new bool[size - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) fork[i] = true; //Init all forks as free

        //Table main loop
        while (true) {
            MPI_Recv(in_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // Recive next message
            philosopher = status.MPI_SOURCE; //Read source of message

            if (status.MPI_TAG == FORK_REQUEST) { //If Request for forks
                printf("Table got philosopher %d fork request\n", philosopher);
                if (fork[philosopher % (size - 1)] == true && fork[philosopher - 1] == true) { //If both forks are free
                    fork[philosopher % (size - 1)] = false; //Set the forks as taken
                    fork[philosopher - 1] = false;
                    MPI_Send(out_buffer, 1, MPI_REAL, philosopher, FORK_RESPONSE, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Send Fork response to the right philosopher
                    printf("Table sent philosopher %d the forks\n", philosopher);
                }
                else //If not both forks are free
                    queue.push_back(philosopher); //Put in wait queue
            }
            if (status.MPI_TAG == FORK_RELEASE) { //If Release of forks
                fork[philosopher % (size - 1)] = true; //Set forks to free again
                fork[philosopher - 1] = true;
                printf("Table got philosopher %d fork release\n", philosopher);

                if (!queue.empty()) { //If philosopher whaiting for forks
                    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = queue.begin(); it != queue.end(); it++) { //Go through whole list of whaiting philosophers
                        philosopher = *it;
                        if (fork[philosopher % (size - 1)] == true && fork[philosopher - 1] == true) { //If one of them can get both forks
                            fork[philosopher % (size - 1)] = false;
                            fork[philosopher - 1] = false;
                            MPI_Send(out_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, philosopher, FORK_RESPONSE, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send Fork response
                            printf("Table sent philosopher %d the forks\n", philosopher);
                            it = queue.erase(it); //Remove from wait list
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (rank) {
        printf("Hello from philosopher %d \n", rank);
        int in_buffer[1];
        int out_buffer[1];
        MPI_Status stat;
        out_buffer[0];
        srand(time(NULL) + rank);

        //Philosopher main loop
        while (true) {
            printf("Philosopher %d is sleeping \n", rank);
            Sleep(rand() % 10); //Sleep
            printf("Philosopher %d is whaiting to eat \n", rank);

            MPI_Send(out_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, FORK_REQUEST, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Request forks
            MPI_Recv(in_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, FORK_RESPONSE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat); //Whait for response
            printf("Philosopher %d is eating \n", rank);
            Sleep(rand() % 10); //Eat
            printf("Philosopher %d is done eating \n", rank);
            MPI_Send(out_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, FORK_RELEASE, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Release forks
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you pasted so  much code, you might have pasted the `#include`'s as well. Also, `Sleep` is undefined.  Could you make your code compile out of the box so that SO users won't have to do completely unnecessary work?

Comment: This works alright on my machine. How do you run the program?

Comment: I run it with "mpiexec -n 6 $(TargetName).exe" and i added includes

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `MPI_REAL` with `MPI_INT`.

**Edit.**
`MPI_REAL` is defined for Fortran interface; in my machine it's value is *different* from `MPI_FLOAT`. See  [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_real). `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` may return an `MPI_ERR_TYPE` value, which indicates "Invalid datatype argument.". So, your implementation may be checking whether the datatype of send and receive buffers are the same and signal some error.

You also have got  uninitialized send/receive buffers, but this is not an error, as their values are unused.

However, I  must stress that your program works fine on my machine, so what you observe must be implementation-dependent. `MPI_REAL` seems a good candidate for a reason for such undefined behavior.

Comment: An explanation of why that would help would be nice ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d Aye, aye, sir!

Comment: I tried it, but it didnt help. Maybe you dant have the error because of the version of MPI?  I have Version 10.1.12498.18, if im not wrong

Comment: I  use OpenMPI 4.0.5 (Linux). `OMPI_MAJOR_VERSION`, `OMPI_MINOR_VERSION`, `OMPI_RELEASE_VERSION`. I'm afraid I can't help any more. Perhaps try to pinpoint the problem with ample usage of `std::cerr`.

Comment: It's also possible that you have a problem with your Windows / software installation. See e.g. https://www.winosbite.com/fix-error-0x80000003/ ;  and also Google for the specific error code.